# Is it possible to use a 2gb library for an Android project?

Tags: java, android

So I'm trying to use a library(TextTeaser for Java) which is around 2.29gb. I tried building an APK without importing stuff from that library but it is giving a IOException error saying that it is exceeding the file size limit. I also set minifyEnabled and shrinkResources to true but it is still giving out the same error.

Are there ways to reduce the file size of a library?

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27471/does-android-have-a-2-1gb-file-size-limit - it may be an issue with files hosted on FAT (eg. SD cards, possibly internal)

Comment: If you are trying to distribute the app via the Play Store, it cannot be anywhere near that large. I think the current limit is 100MB. Probably a lot of that is in native binaries, but even if you used APK splits, I doubt that you can reduce it nearly that far. And that assumes that the native code is available for you in multiple CPU architectures, which may not be the case. Most likely this library is designed for use on servers or desktops, not mobile devices.

Comment: Are there any good automatic text summarization APIs that can be used on mobile phones? Classifier4J's iSummarizer is not reliable.

Comment: what about multidex?